# "Switch" function over discriminated union members in Typescript

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Suppose I have a discriminated union in Typescript:

```js
type MyAction = { type: "redirect", url: string} | {type: "returnValue", value: number}
```

I want to write a "switch expression" which takes a member of the discriminated union and a mapping of types to processor functions, and returns the result of running the correct processor function:

```js
let actionInstance = {type: "returnValue", value: 123} as MyAction
console.log(switchExpression(actionInstance, {
  redirect: (action) => action.url + "(url)",
  returnValue: (action) => `${action.value}` + "(value)"}
))
```

I want the processors to be typed - that is, I want Typescript to error if not all types are represented in the switch, if I provide a key for the switch which is not a valid type, or if I assume the wrong type in a processor function (like I try to access `action.value` in the value for `redirect`).

This is what I've got so far ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCBjYBLA9gOygXigbylEgC4oAiAJwgBMUrkyAaKAVwoBtSBnYClDAOYBfKAB98RCKUoRgbDADUAhuxYQmUAG4q1pDCwC2AIwgUhAWABQVyVABySihTQB3JKkwAeACrM7APhwobygIAA9gCAxqLnxCcCl7KBEAfmCoPQhNUwBuKxsEqABlOWQ2CAAlCEQ0CmpPADEWDGR0DCq5CgxvBMDsKyhBuIBtAGkoflgEVsxhskkyAF1F0gAKbVVEhydXdzbPOD3MZlH-AEocQKaWj3bZeR7IC2tLADNmmawuFxRgRAALACiYTAVC4XH210+HQevXWOkSh0+zEQSi4EC4pBKLDKVCqNTqjQ+txhXUeEHOpChJPuZMKeAGUHYsigryCqPRXGGGzUADpJIsoGioPDNqQlBgQBdsFdiW1Sd0EnlLIMqJ0sK9RWozlZnlZmcAhZ8AJIYHgSxDQXB4STSNXyZSbDQ8xIARgATABmETCpG3Kw1M1oZm89hoASrb6-AHA0EYiGYVZKE1m4AWiDMBkqqBUWj0YBrZO3aWBIttXlsdhQADU5FWlbOTEZ9q6jt0IrLmBLUAABgASPCdjC8l1CHs1usuxvPM46yxAA)), based on a few other answers on StackOverflow:

```js
type NarrowAction<T, N> = T extends { type: N } ? T : never;

type StuctureRecord<FunctionReturnType> =
    { [K in MyAction["type"]]: (value: NarrowAction<MyAction, K>) => FunctionReturnType }

function switchExpression<FunctionReturnType>(value: MyAction, cases: StuctureRecord<FunctionReturnType>): FunctionReturnType {
  let f = cases[value.type] as (value: any) => FunctionReturnType
  return f(value)
}
```

This works correctly, but it's specific to one discriminated union (`MyAction`).

Is there a way to adapt this code to work with *any* discriminated union where all the members have a `type` field, instead of having it only work for `MyAction`? I tried using a type like `DUType extends { type: string }`, but that results in a bunch more errors ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCBjYBLA9gOygXigbylEgC4oAiAJwgBMUrkyAaKAVwoBtSBnYClDAOYBfKAB98RCKUoRgbDADUAhuxYQmUAG4q1pDCwC2AIwgUhAWABQVyVABySihTQB3JKkwAeACrM7APhwobygIAA9gCAxqLnxCcCl7KBEAfmCoPQhNUwBuKxsEqABlOWQ2CAAlCEQ0CmpPABEAVW9C8Mjo2LxJbl5%20YWYAMRYMZHQMKrkKDFbIQOwrKCW4gG0AaSh%20KGbZiBWySTIAXSPSAAptVUSHJ1d3cc84e8xmNf8AShxA4dGPCdl5LsLNZLAAzEZjTBQLguFDARAACwAomEwFQuFwHjs2hEojEJAlenxBEIhhC-pNAQl-BcdIknpCMMxEEouBAuKQSiwylQqjU6o0Wgkyb9xpTprsPqQfozxTNCnhFlB2LIoKCgiy2VwVpc1AA6SRHJUAemNUAAAsAuABaFACDC1CBKqhTLCg2lXd5WYFWFXAKBKRkASQwPCUo2guG6hPILvkyiuGl1iQAjAAmADMIlZsAQjKsNVDaBVevYaAEZxhcMRKLR7MxmDOgb%20IbDEeYissSyotHowHOzfGn2wgUHmD1bHYUAA1OQzpP3kxnQDpgndFAm4zh4EAAYAEjwY4weuTQh3M7nycXwPeXssQA))

Note: I know I can use the `StructuredRecord` directly or I could just use a regular `switch` statement or if/else statements with an `assertUnreachable` function ([StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript)), but I'm interested in whether a solution in the above form exist due to academic curiosity, and that fact that it would be an ergonomic util function to have to ensure type safety without having to type all the type annotations directly.

Comment: You are likely hitting the problem mentioned in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and you just need to deal with the fact that the compiler can't properly analyze `cases[value.type](value)`.  I will likely close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56781010/2887218 unless you can articulate an important distinction for part 1 of your question.

Comment: Note:  you should be using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and not [`//@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments).  The latter should be used "*very sparingly*", as it can lead to weird side effects.

Comment: For part 2 of your question, it seems like this should be broken into a separate question (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/mpvKbw) is how I'd probably do things for part 2 of your question, which still has to use type assertions in the implementation of `switchExpression()` and changes to a curried function to avoid having to infer both `A` and `R` generic types at the same time as contextually typing the callback parameters, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872 for that limitation.  I would write this up as an answer for a standalone part 2.  If you could pick one of your two questions to make the focus of this question and remove the other one, that would be helpful.

Comment: Wow, looks like I'm not the only one who's had this problem! Thanks for the detailed feedback and for curating the list of SO questions on that github issue. I've edited the answer to focus on part 2, so happy to accept your answer from the linked playground if you write it up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a discriminated union where the `type` property is a discriminant, you can expand `StructureRecord` to:

```
type StuctureRecord<A extends { type: string }, R> =
  { [T in A as T["type"]]: (value: T) => R }
```

where `R` corresponds to your `FunctionReturnType` type parameter (I like to follow the [naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344160/2887218) so you can easily tell a type parameter apart from a specific type), and `A` is the discriminated union type.

This is similar to yours except I'm using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over the entire discriminated union type `A` instead of over the `type` property of `A`.  By doing `T in A` I'm able to get each member of the union type in term, and just use it as the function parameter type.  Otherwise you have to do `K in A["type"]` and then use `K` to recreate `T` from `A` with something like [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), like you're doing with `NarrowAction`.  This change is just for elegance/convenience and doesn't really affect any behavior we care about.

---

At this point we could just add another generic type parameter `A` to `switchExpression` corresponding to the discriminated union:

```
const switchExpression =
  <A extends { type: string }, R>(value: A, cases: StuctureRecord<A, R>): R => {
    const type: A["type"] = value.type;
    const f = cases[type] as (value: any) => R;
    return f(value);
  }
```

Note that I have moved `type` to its own variable and [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as type `A["type"]`.  If you just write `value.type` the compiler will eagerly resolve that to `string` because `A extends {type: string}`.  But we don't want that, since `cases` will be known to have keys in `A["type"]` but not just `string`.  This saves us from needing another [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to write `cases[type as A["type"]]`.

But since we need that `cases[type] as (value: any) => R` in there, it doesn't matter that much.  There's a fundamental limitation of TypeScript where the compiler just can't do the higher order reasoning to see that for each member `T` of the `A` union, `StructureRecord<T, R>[T["type"]]` will be of type `(value: T) => R` and thus it will always be safe to call `cases[value.type](value)`.  The correlation between `cases[value.type]` and  `value` over the different possible narrowings of `A` is lost.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.  Thus, inside the implementation of `switchExpression` you should just use as many type assertions as you need to avoid errors, triple check that your assertions are reasonable and that you're not allowing unsafe things, and move on.

---

So that's great.  Unfortunately, when you call `switchExpression()`, you see a problem with type inference:

```
switchExpression(actionInstance, {
  redirect: (action) => action.url + "(url)",
  // ------> ~~~~~~ // error, action is implicitly any
  returnValue: (action) => `${action.value}` + "(value)"
  // ---------> ~~~~~~ // error, action is implicitly any    
}).toUpperCase(); // <-- error, object is of type unknown
```

Here the compiler does infer `A` to be `MyAction`, but the callback parameters of `action` are implicitly [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and not the expected members of the `MyAction` union.  This is another limitation of TypeScript.  In this case we need the compiler to infer both the type parameters `A` and `R` as well as the types of the two callback parameters named `action` based on [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing). The compiler tries to do this all at once and fails to get `action` right because it depends on `A` which it doesn't know yet. And `R` also fails to be inferred, falls back to `unknown`, and then the compiler won't let you use the return value easily.

There are various issues in GitHub around this problem; see [microsoft/TypeScript#25092](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25092) for one of them.  Whenever you want both generic type inference and contextual callback parameter type inference at once, you run the risk of this kind of issue.

You *could* cut the knot by manually specifying both `A` and `R`:

```
switchExpression<MyAction, string>(actionInstance, {
  redirect: (action) => action.url + "(url)",
  returnValue: (action) => `${action.value}` + "(value)"
}).toUpperCase(); // okay
```

but that's a bit sad.

---

Instead we could work around the problem by making `switchExpression` into a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function which takes `value` and returns a function that takes `cases`.  The original function will be able to infer `A` properly, after which the compiler only needs to infer `R` and `action`, because `A` is already set in stone:

```
const switchExpression =
  <A extends { type: string }>(value: A) =>
    <R,>(cases: StuctureRecord<A, R>): R => {
      const type: A["type"] = value.type;
      const f = cases[type] as (value: any) => R;
      return f(value);
    }
```

That's not much of a change, really.  And you call it like this:

```
switchExpression(actionInstance)({
  redirect: (action) => action.url + "(url)",
  returnValue: (action) => `${action.value}` + "(value)"
}).toUpperCase(); // okay
```

If you squint you can think of `)(` as being like `,` when you call `switchExpression`.  But you can see that type inference has occurred exactly as we want.  `A` is inferred as `MyAction` in the first call, and so can be used to contextually type `action` in the second call, which allows the compiler to infer `R` in turn.

Personally I'd rather use currying and get nice type inference than a single function call and have to manually specify types, but it's up to you what makes sense for your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCBjYBLA9gOygXigbylEgC4oAiAJwgBMUrkyAaKAVwoBtSBnYClDAOZQAvlAA++QuAilKEYGwwA1AIbsWEJlABuajaQwsAtgCMIFEQFgAUO3lQVydBgCSGHioyJouAkRnkVAoUynqazLrqAQCMAEwAzCIOXLAITpg2mdb+UADKCshsEABKEIhoFNQAPPBQEAAewBAY1Cl+0ty8-ELCzMUAfDg2UJIA2gAqUPxQtSop46Nk-mQAuiukABSR+lDjAJQ4g8VW1jbl7sBQXCrUuQDuKMCIABYAovVgVFxczkPWIzU6o1mq1JP5OnxBCI+v0tmFSPBmIg5hAuKR8ixClRSuVKjUYXtSMdsIM8MMRlBzjwpCQZotliscDowgA6fwAbnJIyplwAZkzkVxUaN-Iy5lA4VFSJ4QAcSVBipz-hSgoooLzJRo9kqRsIslS0HYWew0AINtdbg8nm8Pl8fpgNo5UJg3B4vBBmGTlVRaPRgJsnc45YNA5gWWx2FAANTkDYRvZMckAeiTUAAtBnM4MAH65vNQFN1CgUCrMUNYFApFBGMDsFCIR7sEAODAgcmqkKqKUS8vBqAAAwAJHhyyzthBhP3o7Hxwnk6nM4uMzm87mC6nzCWKGX0hWqzW6w3gE2W23rMI9my0ABVMCQCgAYRRGz22vXUCqGaLW+YaBMACsykuSsoDQfkchYDAAGsMDQO4MCyQsjE8Fg1BPLhIAbXkzwNI0TTNC17keF53k+VF7QwKo4CQZ0MGYHhIQEWFy1dYBPG8T12xoOggIDXc+1HCNpzIOMOATRguOCUJu0dfjDgHYdR3HSdhM1CA53PS9gBvO9zCfIUX21fVMGpLgrRI21yN+bByUBBomhaNoaQCBjuhEWFxwRYMuQ-YpGFhQVUXRApghKMoKmqREFX6QkFXkr0KQpHlnIRelpFWJlxzZaQdUSykTL5AUUS4EVpDFFI1OlVs+0VHyRg7LANVnXLdWM9xDQgY1TXNcybTI75nFk2jWPY9SNgSqAfR45A+NogTd3DDhVPjRNvXkRQux2Iag3kocRwW5SpxjETZzIGwLyvW9730iBDKVGwgA)

Comment: Lovely, thank you so much again for the detailed explanation! It's going to take some time to wrap my head around all the concepts here but the playground link is great. Thank you!